# Insert Records From GridView to another GridView Page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, records, microsoft-expression-web

Can somebody help me?
I am developing a website using Microsoft Expression Web. My database is MS Access. My page extension is .aspx (ASP.NET)

I have two gridview:

1. `Pending Records GridView` should be under a `PendingRecords.aspx` page. I want this gridview to allow me to accept first all the requested records before they go straight under the Main Gridview. Of course, the gridview have "ADD" button. When I click the button, I want the records to be transfer in Main Records GridView.
2. `Main GridView` should be under a `Records.aspx` page. I want this gridview to display all the records that I already accepted in Pending Records Gridview.

Simple as that!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I doubt you will get anyone to create these pages for you, so you will have to try something yourself, then ask a new question once you have a specific technical questions.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Kjartan I already have the .aspx pages and gridviews as mention above. I made a sample registration page and when i click the submit button, the records are displayed on my pendingrecords.aspx. Now, i want to accept the records first and automatically transfer it to mainrecords.aspx after accepting it.

Answer (score -1):

one the button click event save the data from first gridview into the session and when load it again in the second gridview when page loads or reloads.
it will work if you don't have much data to move.....
hope will give you some idea.... :)

Comment: first option is saving the data in the sessions and moving to another gridview. simplest

Comment: and the second option is You could take the contents of the first GridView and put them into a DataTable.  Then use the DataTable as the source for the second GridView.  When populating the DataTable, just filter out items that aren't checked.

Here is someone else's example on populating a DataTable from a GridView: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=474895

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try that tomorrow :)) hope it will work. its already late night here. And still suffering to this project LOL